# python: which wxpython to install on win8?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am using the following version of Python: 2.7.5 and I installed this version of wxPython: 2.8.12.1. When I run the code below I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>          File "", line 1, in  win.show()
>       AttributeError: 'Frame' object has no attribute 'show'

Code:

```
>>>import wx
>>> app=wx.App()
>>> win=wx.Frame(None)
>>> win.show()
```

I am new to programming, what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add:

```
win.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

I'm also pretty sure you need to include an ID and Title in the Frame class:

```
win = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'Title')
win.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

**EDIT**

I forgot to capitalize the `Show` method in wx. That is your main error.